# Not able to show the selected form choice in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

forms.py

```
PERSON_ACTIONS = (
    ('1', '01.Allowed to rest and returned to class'),
    ('2', '02.Contacted parents /guardians'),
    ('3', '02a.- Unable to Contact'),
    ('4', '02b.Unavailable - left message'),

class PersonActionsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    action = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), choices=PERSON_ACTIONS, required=False)
```

views.py

```
def person(request):
    action= Actions.objects.filter(reportperson=person_id)
    return render(request, 'index.html',
             {
              'action':action,
                 })
```

models.py

```
class Actions(models.Model):
    """Action list to a report"""
    reportperson = models.ForeignKey(ReportPerson)
    action =  models.IntegerField('Action type',choices=PERSON_ACTIONS)
```

template

```
{{ action.get_action_display }}
```

From django [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/) for choices field,i did this but it is not working.In database their values are saved as "3","4".I expected that it will display the value like "02a.- Unable to Contact","02b.Unavailable - left message" instead of  "3","4" etc.It is not displaying any thing.

How to make this work.

Thanks

Comment: did the changes as Daniel said,still not working can i get a guidence from anybody

Comment: Your code does not make sense. You're defining `PersonActionsForm` but you don't use it anywhere. You're using an `Actions` model in your view which you haven't shown us. How are we going to help you?

Comment: @rantanplan,updated the models.py and PersonActionsForm is used to save the choices

Comment: 1) `action` is an `IntegerField`, which means it can save one integer value. Yet in your form you override the widget to a multiple select, but it can't save multiple values. 2) the `filter` has got to go as Daniel said. 3) Try to run it(with `get` instead of `filter`) inside the python interpret and post the results.

Comment: @rantanplan getting this error in console ">>> Actions.objects.get(pk=person_id)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'person_id' is not defined
"

Comment: Yeah well instead of `person_id`, which you haven't defined, pass it an *existing* pk, like Actions.objects.get(pk=1).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31786/discussion-between-royal-and-rantanplan)

Answer (score 0):

`filter` always returns a QuerySet, not a model instance. You should use `get` instead.